# Z axis not working as expected with some sprites

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a parallax, the script is not mine but it is reliable, I just have to order the layers in the Z axis.

Until now, I have only added backgrounds, but today I started adding foregrounds, and one sprite respects the order, and the rest don't.

I played with the Z axis on those that didn't work, but they are unable to be shown behind another parallax layer.

That makes me think that it is a issue with the sprite configuration or the image itself. Any clue what could it be?, I'm lost now...

[image]

Comment: You should use the sort order on the sprite renderer instead of relying on the z...

Comment: Wow it worked thanks! I have studied Unity at college and the guy who taught us seems to know nothing about unity. I always did this with Z axis...